# Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1 navbar-right overflows navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm experimenting with the Carousel example in Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1 and I've fallen at the first hurdle.  I want to add a right-aligned search box to the navigation bar, so I've added the following code (I've included some of the existing code for context):

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- my insertion starts here -->
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
          </form>
          <!-- my insertion ends here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The inserted code was taken from Twitter Bootstrap's "Default navbar" on the Components page.  I've inserted it in the equivalent position of the Carousel's navbar, changing "navbar-left" to "navbar-right" .  Unfortunately, the search box overhangs the right hand side of the navigation bar by about 15-20 pixels (I've also removed the Submit button from the above example, but if I put it back in, the submit button overhangs the navigation bar in the same way).  What have I done wrong here?

(Edit: included the whole navbar section as requested)

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: No, I downloaded the docs and made the edits on my local machine.

Comment: @DamianWalker could you include all of the navbar html?

Comment: The effects I describe can now be seen at http://www.eternam.co.uk/bootstrap/test.html.  With all the bootstrap files needed, I'm not sure how I can use jsfiddle for this example.

Comment: @Thunda Thanks, I've edited the example to include the whole navbar section now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the inner container to container-fluid so it can allow the div to strech. Check this out:

http://www.bootply.com/115744

So this

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

**EDIT**
Whoops I accidentally switched your divs to navs.